# docker - unable to find package (two servers with same setup except version)

Tags: proxy, apt, docker

Does newer Docker have different source list or something?

```
a# docker --version
Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765

b# docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Install goes through the older one but not the new.

```
"
E: Unable to locate package supervisor
E: Unable to locate package python-pystache
"
```

This is basic Dockerfile on both:

```
# cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV http_proxy 'http://proxy.us.wsa.com:80'
ENV https_proxy 'http://proxy.us.wsa.com:80'
ENV HTTP_PROXY 'http://proxy.us.wsa.com:80'
ENV HTTPS_PROXY 'http://proxy.us.wsa.com:80'
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive 
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y vim supervisor python2.7 openjdk-7-jdk python-pystache make

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Both servers a and b have SAME proxy setup, etc in `/etc/environment` and `/etc/default/docker`.

Tried below like some other folks suggested:

```
"
RUN add-apt-repository main
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN add-apt-repository restricted
RUN add-apt-repository multivers
"
```

But "`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`"

Out of clue here.

Thanks, yet again.

Comment: I don't think Docker 1.10 is ready for prime time. There have been numerous problems reported with it, including complete data loss on upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Michael Hampton" is correct. Always to stay away from bleeding edge when looking for stability.

```
a# docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

All fine.

```
Selecting previously unselected package libgraphite2-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgraphite2-3_1.2.4-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgraphite2-3:amd64 (1.2.4-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libharfbuzz0b:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libharfbuzz0b_0.9.27-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libharfbuzz0b:amd64 (0.9.27-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpangoft2-1.0-0_1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 (1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpangocairo-1.0-0_1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
```

In case people wonder, these are simple steps to install a specific version of Docker. And sometimes, when it complains of existing dependency, remove that individual dependency manually before downgrading/upgrading.

```
  274  sudo apt-get remove -y docker-engine
  286  wget https://get.docker.io/ | DOCKER_VERSION=1.9.1 sh --proxy=on
  287  history | grep docker
  288  ls
  289  apt-get install -y docker-engine=1.9.1
  290  exit
```